# How do I extract the three principal palm lines

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision

I have tried "Canny Edge Detection". The result was not good. Are there some mature methods to extract the three principal palm lines?

Comment: This question is a bit to open. Please specify a bit more clearly what you tried and what you want to do. Image recognition is a difficult task and there might be dozens of reasons why a certain algorithm fails on certain images.

Comment: I agree with @PMF - there may be many reasons why you don't get a good result, but without seeing at least some images and ideally some code too, it will be difficult to make sensible suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best algorithms as of today for edge/contour detection is "Contour Detection and Hierarchical Image Segmentation" by Arbelaez et al. The code can be found here http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/grouping/resources.html